# Ad Hoc Testing preparing for beta test

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, ad-hoc-distribution

I have  Ad Hoc distribution certificate, but I am not having private key  associated with that certificate; so do i need private key.OR, Is there any other way. I have email-id and password of the developer whose has signed as iOS developer with apple.
If ad hoc testing build is succeeded, how can we recognize
kindly help me to resolve this problem

Thanks In Advance......

Comment: without the private key you can't sign applications. that's the whole point of app signing. Ask the developer with the private key to sign your app.

Comment: means I need ask for private key from our root developer. after that I can follow instruction provided by Apple...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use the free TestFlight system (http://www.testflightapp.com), it makes the whole process a breeze.

Comment: @clafou...  I am using testflight.com and i am using Instruction provided by them to create .ipa. Ref:http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402782-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4   . Everything working before  Archiving and Packaging. And I am very much sure that I have followed their instruction properly except they are saying to  create  Entitlements as 1. go to file ->New-> New File. 2. Under cod e signing, select Entitlement . But this option is showing in my Xcode 4.2 . so I am plist file like Entitlements.plist. Kindly help me out thanks......

Comment: Have a root around their articles or their forum, I vaguely remember finding a post about how to get this done in the latest XCode!